# cannot load such file -- chef/mixin/language

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I am testing a cook book on my local machine using Kitchen. I get the below error.

```
    Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/windows/libraries/windows_package.rb
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.333373 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: ================================================================================
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.333444 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: 
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.333714 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: LoadError
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.333755 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: ---------
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.333933 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: cannot load such file -- chef/mixin/language
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.333976 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: 
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.334003 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: Cookbook Trace:
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.334036 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: ---------------
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.334059 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404:   /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/windows/libraries/windows_package.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.334082 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: 
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.334365 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: Relevant File Content:
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.334399 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: ----------------------
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.334463 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/windows/libraries/windows_package.rb:
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.334600 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: 
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.334826 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404:   1:  require 'chef/resource/lwrp_base'
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.334870 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404:   2:  require 'chef/provider/lwrp_base'
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.334919 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404:   3:  
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.334956 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404:   4:  require 'win32/registry' if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin|mingw32|windows/
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.334981 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404:   5:  
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.335013 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404:   6:  require 'chef/mixin/shell_out'
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.335314 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404:   7>> require 'chef/mixin/language'
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.335425 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404:   8:  class Chef
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.335457 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404:   9:    class Provider
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.335483 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404:  10:      class WindowsCookbookPackage < Chef::Provider::LWRPBase
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.335508 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404:  11:        include Chef::Mixin::ShellOut
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.335531 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404:  12:        include Windows::Helper
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.335556 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404:  13:  
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.335579 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404:  14:        # the logic in all action methods mirror that of
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.335638 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404:  15:        # the Chef::Provider::Package which will make
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.335669 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404:  16:        # refactoring into core chef easy
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.335872 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: 
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.336010 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: System Info:
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.336042 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: ------------
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.336067 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: chef_version=14.0.202
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.336090 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: platform=ubuntu
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.336112 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: platform_version=14.04
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.336134 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: ruby=ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.336158 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: program_name=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client
I, [2018-04-18T15:52:46.336186 #55288]  INFO -- default-ubuntu-1404: executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client
```

I know that some of mixins were removed form chef client version > 14.*

I want to know why does it installs this package and how to correct this?

Answer (score 9):

That mixin was indeed removed in Chef 14, however that file was removed in version 3.0 of that cookbook because the `windows_package` resource was moved into Chef core. If you upgrade that cookbook to the latest version (or just something newer than 3.0) it should work.